# How to write text on image using opencv python in run-time application

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying using opencv python codes for my mini project that is Basic paint application.

I want to write a text on my image in run-time application. Not before running the code or hard coded text. How can I do that?

I need help for that, Thanks.

Comment: Please read my problem statement again ...this might look duplicate but its not.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here is how its done in OpenCV

You can add text to your image using `cv2.putText()` function
For example: 
`cv2.putText(img,'OpenCV',(10,500), font, 4, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)`

Check [THIS LINK](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html) for more details

Here is an example:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread(path + 'pillar.png', 1)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(im, 'Christmas', (10,450), font, 3, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imwrite(path + 'pillar_text.jpg', im)
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

I used the `chr()` function to enter the values of the keys being entered. For every character typed the image would be updated in a `while` loop. Here is a sample code:

```
import cv2
path = "C:/Users//Desktop/ocean.jpg"

img = cv2.imread(path)

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

i = 10
while(1):
    cv2.imshow('img',img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(33)
    if k==27:    # Esc key to stop
        break
    elif k==-1:  # normally -1 returned,so don't print it
        continue
    else:
        print (k) # else print its value
       cv2.putText(img, chr(k), (i, 50), font, 1, (0, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        i+=15

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

***Instructions:***

1. Press any key to enter its value
2. Press `Esc` key to end the program

Comment: Thanks for replying.... I did that before what you have shown up there...That is okay..But my point is how can I write or type text on already opened Image.?

Like Say..The program for importing and displaying image, and after executing your program at run-time when your image is popup on screen, that time we have to write text on that image..

I hope you will understand what I am saying.!!! Thanks

Comment: like we use "Insert text into the picture" tool from Paint. "A" looking symbol in Paint.

Comment: @Niranjankulkarni have a look at the update and see if it suits your requirement

Comment: Thanks ...that works for me. I will make changes accordingly. Appreciated.

Comment: @JeruLuke i have an error  when i tried this code :
SystemError: <built-in function putText> returned NULL without setting an error

Comment: @sayedashraf Check whether the coordinates (x and y) are within the image